# If a random variable converge in distribution then scalar multiplication also converges in distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let c be a constant and suppose that $X_n\xrightarrow{d}X$, prove that

i)  $cX_n\xrightarrow{d}cX$ 
ii) $X_n+c\xrightarrow{d}X+c$

I've tried to use that:

$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} F_{cX_n}(x) = lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(cX_n\leq x) = lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P\left(X_n\leq \dfrac{x}{c}\right) = lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} F_{X_n}\left(\dfrac{x}{c}\right) $

But that's not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: For (i) you may need to take care over the sign of $c$ and whether $c=0$

Comment: What is wrong with what you’ve shown?

Comment: @Bey Because what has been shown is not even true for $c = 1$; pointwise limits of cumulative distribution functions need only hold at points for which the limiting c.d.f is continuous. For instance, take $X_n$ such that $P(X_n = 1/n) = 1$.

Comment: @snar I don't see your point.  As of right now, they've basically just written $F_{cX_n}(x) = F_{X_n}\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)$ which is true for all $x$ and all $c > 0$.  It's incomplete and the limit is a bit premature, but not false.  To finish using OP's method we would just need to show $F_{cX}$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $F_{X}$ is continuous at $x/c$. (and obviously $c \leq 0$ would need to be dealt with separately)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remember that $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$ it's by definition:
$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{X_n} (x) = F_X(x)$

Hence:
a)
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{cX_n} (x) & = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} (cX_n \leq x)  \\
 & = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( X_n \leq \dfrac{x}{c} \right) \\
 & = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{X_n} \left(\dfrac{x}{c}\right) \\
 & =  F_{X} \left(\dfrac{x}{c}\right) \\
 & =  \mathbb{P} \left( X \leq \dfrac{x}{c} \right) \\
 & =  \mathbb{P} \left( cX \leq x \right) \\
 & =  F_{cX} \left({x}\right) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\therefore \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{cX_n} (x) =  F_{cX} \left({x}\right) \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\therefore cX_n \xrightarrow{d} cX
\end{equation*}

Analogously:
b)
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{split}
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{X_{n}+c} (x) & = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} (X_n + c \leq x)  \\
 & = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( X_n \leq x-c \right) \\
 & = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{X_n} \left( x-c \right) \\
 & =  F_{X} \left( x-c \right) \\
 & =  \mathbb{P} \left( X \leq x-c \right) \\
 & =  \mathbb{P} \left( X+c \leq x \right) \\
  & =  F_{X+c} \left( x \right) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\therefore \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{X_{n}+c} (x) =  F_{X+c} \left({x}\right)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\therefore X_n+c \xrightarrow{d} X+c
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ (denoted $X_n \Rightarrow X$) if and only if, for any bounded continuous function $f$ (denoted $f \in C_b$), we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[f(X_n)] = E[f(X)].$$
Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ be given. The maps $g_c^\times(x) = cx$ and $g_c^+(x) = x + c$ are continuous, so for any $f \in C_b$, $f\circ g_c^\times$ and $f\circ g_c^+$ are also in $C_b$. Therefore, because $X_n \Rightarrow X$ we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[f(X_n^{c,\times})] = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[(f\circ g_c^\times)(X_n)] = E[(f\circ g_c^\times)(X)] = E[f(X_c^\times)],$$
and ditto for $X_n^{c,+}$.